# PHP Includes cannot access objects on main page

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm using the template engine specified below. While everything works well, when I include variables/objects from the main page (e.g index.php) in the template file e.g (main.php), the object cannot be accessed.

The reason I'm doing this is because in my template file, I want to check whether a user is logged in, and display a different header respectively.

But when I attempt to print out a value, I get the error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object".

The User Account and Template class are both independent.

In my template file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php if ($user->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
        <HEADER 1>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <HEADER 1>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My template engine:

```
class Template
{
    protected $template;
    protected $variables = array();

    public function __construct($template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->variables[$key];
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->variables[$key] = $value;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        extract($this->variables);
        chdir(dirname($this->template));
        ob_start();

        include basename($this->template);

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

index.php

```
require 'global.php';

require 'templateEngine.php';

$user = new Account(); // the $user object works when I print it on the same page, but not when it's in the template file. 

$view = new Template("path/to/template.php");

$view->title = "Hello world!";
$view->description = "This is a ridiculously simple template";

echo $view;
```

What should I do so that my template file can access my $user object, generated from index.php?

**Note: the template engine uses 'Includes', hence the title - but I may be wrong.**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any include or require in the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The include is generated via the templating class.

Comment: Where is the `new` Object instance that is assigned to `$user`? Please show us the `class` `isLoggedIn()` belongs to.

Comment: *duh*, my mistake. *Long day*.

Comment: @PHPglue I've added the index.php now. Sorry for that!

Comment: Pass `$user` into the constructor (or any other method for that matter) of the template class and store it as a property of the class

Comment: Do you mean `class Template extends Account`? Otherwise, you will have to pass an argument.

Comment: @PHPglue the two classes are currently independent. Should my Template extends Account?

Comment: A class does not have access to another class unless it extends that class, or you pass an instantiated class into a method.

Comment: You could add `protected user; public function setUser($user){$this->user = $user; return $this;}` to your `Template` class.

Comment: In the index file you need to make the _$user_ available to the template: _`$view->user = $user`_.

Comment: @RyanVincent Apologies for my ignorance. But does doing that mean that I'll be using more resources? Since $user already exists with data, I'm simply creating another clone of it using your way. Is there a way of making use of the existing $user object?

Comment: The resource use in a template is not something to be concerned about - even large html pages sent out aren't that big. Whatever in this case a reference is passed so do not think about resource use. Make the program work first.

Comment: @Jas Unless you specifically call `clone`, you aren't cloning anything. Using `$view->user = $user` will set the existing `$user` object as a reference in your view. See http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: If there are this many comments, you need to write the question better.

Comment: @PHPglue apologies for my failed attempt at phrasing my question. How can I improve? Also, I can no longer see your answer posted earlier, did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Jas I'd suggest you stop asking questions in the comments here, read the comments that have already been posted (which sum up what you need to do many times over), read the manual and try some stuff out. [Here's a practical example to get you started](https://eval.in/309714)

Comment: @scrowler Given my standard in PHP, I definitely have problems understanding some of the answers here, and that's why I tried to clarify. But thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Thanks everyone for your answers!